# c# razor url parameter from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, razor

Why does `Request["parameterName"]` returns null within the view? I know I can get it from the controller but I have to make a little check in the View. I am using ASP.NET MVC 3.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Request.Params["paramName"]
```

See also:
[When do Request.Params and Request.Form differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706/when-do-request-params-and-request-form-differ)

Comment: Nice! Worked! you have my +1! :)

Comment: This only works for parameters which are after "?", not for route parameters.

Answer (score 42):

I've found the solution [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248064/how-to-get-query-string-parameter-from-mvc-razor-markup)

```
@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["parameterName"])
```

Comment: This will only work if the query string parameter is also a parameter on the action.

Answer (score 10):

```
@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["parameterName"])
```

worked with ROUTE PARAM.

```
Request.Params["paramName"]
```

did not work with ROUTE PARAM.

Answer (score 6):

If you're doing the check inside the View, put the value in the `ViewBag`.

In your controller:

```
ViewBag["parameterName"] = Request["parameterName"];
```

It's worth noting that the `Request` and `Response` properties are exposed by the `Controller` class. They have the same semantics as `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse`.

Comment: yes but my question is whether I can get it directly from the View, without using the controller?

Comment: You've already stated that Request["parameterName"] returns null in your view. Your question seemed more about making a check in the View, which you can do using this solution. What's stopping you from wanting to use the ViewBag?

Comment: That's an habit, in general I try to avoid ViewBags in favor of Model.

Comment: Is this data part of the model though? From what you said, you simply want to check some condition in order to do something else?

Comment: Either way, it seems odd that the values are different between view and controller - they should be referencing the same exact Request object.

Comment: The Request object is a property of the Controller class. I may be mistaken, but I dont think the view has access to that property of the Controller class.

Comment: For those of you who get an exception "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject'", just replace ViewBag with ViewData (source:http://forums.asp.net/t/1800747.aspx/1)

Answer (score 2):

.Net Core 7
`@Requst.Query["ParamName"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
@(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Query["parameterName"].FirstOrDefault()) ?? "")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.